# Integrals with $\operatorname{sech}$ substitution

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

Consider the integral:

$$\int \frac{da}{a\sqrt{s-a^2}} \quad da  = \pm \int dx.$$

Which is to be evaluated using $a = \operatorname{sech}{(\theta)}$ to give $\theta = \pm x$. how might one complete such an integral using this substitution? Computing the integral in any software (e.g. Matlab, Mathematica) reveals an answer in terms of $\arctan$, not $\operatorname{sech}$.

Comment: What are you assuming about $s$? How does it vanish when you do that substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$a = \sqrt{s} \operatorname{sech} (\theta) \tag{1}$$

$$da = -\sqrt{s} \tanh(\theta)\operatorname{sech}(\theta) d\theta \tag{2}$$

$$\int \frac{da}{a\sqrt{s-a^2}} = 
\int \frac{   -\sqrt{s} \tanh(\theta)\operatorname{sech}(\theta)  }{\sqrt{s} \, \operatorname{sech}(\theta)\sqrt{s-s\,\operatorname{sech}^2(\theta)}} d\theta \tag{3}$$

$$\int \frac{da}{a\sqrt{s-a^2}} = 
\int \frac{   -\tanh(\theta)  }{\sqrt{s} \, \sqrt{1-\operatorname{sech}^2(\theta)}} d\theta \tag{4}$$

$$1 - \operatorname{sech}^2(\theta) = \tanh^2(\theta) \tag{5}$$

$$\int \frac{da}{a\sqrt{s-a^2}}  = 
\int \frac{   \pm \tanh(\theta)  }{\sqrt{s} \tanh(\theta)} d\theta \tag{6}$$

The $\pm$ comes from the square root. Usually only the $+$ branch is taken.

$$\int \frac{da}{a\sqrt{s-a^2}}  = \int \frac{\pm1}{\sqrt{s}}  d\theta \tag{7}$$

$$\int \frac{da}{a\sqrt{s-a^2}}  = \frac{\pm \theta}{\sqrt{s}} +c_1\tag{8}$$

$$\pm \int dx = \pm x + c_2 \tag{9}$$

$$ \frac{\theta}{\sqrt{s}} = \pm x +c_3\tag{10}$$

$c_1,c_2,c_3$ are unknown constants of integration.

If $s=1$ then $\theta = \pm x +c$.

Comment: Sebastiano - \operatorname - thanks.

Comment: So, the way the OP is stated, I think that $s$ should have been $1$ from the start.

Comment: GEdgar - I can't see how else it could work.

Comment: Ahhh, I See, thanks :)